# How to separate reading a file from adding data to queue

Tags: c#, .net, producer-consumer

My case is like this:
I am building an application that can read data from some source (files or database) and write that data to another source (files or database).

So, basically I have objects:

`InputHandler` -> `Queue` -> `OutputHandler`

Looking at a situation where input is some files, `InputHandler` would:
1. Use `FilesReader` to read data from all the files (`FilesReader` encapsulates the logic of reading files and it returns a collection of objects)
2. Add the objects to queue.

(and then it repeats infinitely since `InputHandler` has a while loop that looks for new files all the time).

The problem appears when files are really big - `FilesReader`, which reads all files and parses them, is not the best idea here. It would be much better if I could somehow read a portion of the file, parse it, and put it in a queue - and repeat it until the end of each file.

It is doable using Streams, however, I don't want my `FilesReader` to know anything about the queue - it feels to me that it breaks OOP rule of separation of concerns.

Could you suggest me a solution for this issue?

//UPDATE

Here's some code that shows (in simplified way) what `InputHandler` does:

```cs
public class InputHandler {
  public Task Start() {
    while(true) {
      var newData = await _filesReader.GetData();
      _queue.Enqueue(newData);
    }
  }
}
```

This code shows how the code looks like right now. So, if I have 1000 files, each having lots and lots of data, `_filesReader` will try to read all this data and return it - and memory would quickly be exhausted.

Now, if `_filesReader` was to use streams and return data partially, the memory usage would be kept low.

One solution would be to have `_queue` object inside of `_filesReader` - it could just read data from stream and push directly to queue - I don't like it - too much responsibility for `_filesReader`.

Another solution (as proposed by jhilgeman) - `filesReader` could raise events with the data in them.

Is there some other solution?

Comment: Please share what code you have so far. It's difficult to infer from the question what the exact problem is and how best to advise you without some code samples.

Comment: You mentioned parsing of files. What kind of parsing is this? Are you talking about CSV files for example, that can be parsed line by line?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well, I would like to support CSV and JSON. I guess I would have CsvFilesReader and JsonFilesReader

Comment: @PatrickTucci I added some code and some more explanation

Comment: @Loreno how can you parse a portion of a JSON file? These files can only be parsed as a whole!

Comment: Why are you using two users?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I changed my mail at some point and created new account. I wasn't even aware that on one of my computers I'm logged in on the other account :)

Comment: *I don't want my FilesReader to know anything about the queue* <--- what do you mean by that? Isn't it necessary for the FilesReader to know that there is a queue? Otherwise where will it send its output for further processing?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What I mean is that I don't want FilesReader to be kind of hardcoded to always rely on queue. I might want to reuse FilesReader in another scenario where there is no queue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand why using an IO stream of some kind would change the way you would add objects to the queue.

However, what I would personally do is set up a static custom event in your FilesReader class, like OnObjectRead. Use a stream to read through files and as you read a record, raise the event and pass that object/record to it.

Then have an event subscriber that takes the record and pushes it into the Queue. It would be up to your app architecture to determine the best place to put that subscriber.

On a side note, you mentioned your InputHandler has a while loop that looks for new files all the time. I'd strongly recommend you don't use a while loop for this if you're only checking the filesystem. This is the purpose of FileSystemWatcher - to give you an efficient way to be immediately notified about changes in the filesystem without you having to loop. Otherwise you're constantly grinding the filesystem and constantly eating up disk I/O.

Comment: Good point about FileSystemWatcher - I will look into it, thanks! Regarding your first sentence - the problem is that FileReader does not know anything about queue - it is supposed to be a service that reads files and returns them. When I start to use streams and read/parse files partially, I need a way to somehow "push" them out - your idea with events seems like a good one and, honestly, I've been thinking about it too.

Comment: I guess, `InputHandler` would be the subscriber here. My top level object is `Application` - it executes the `InputHandler` and `OutputHandler` to run in seperate threads connected by one queue.

Answer (score 0):

> This code shows how the code looks like right now. So, if I have 1000 files, each having lots and lots of data, _filesReader will try to read all this data and return it - and memory would quickly be exhausted.

Regarding the problem of unlimited memory consumption, a simple solution is to replace the _queue with a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1). This class has bounding capabilities out of the box.

```
public class InputHandler
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _buffer
        = new BlockingCollection<string>(boundedCapacity: 10);

    public Task Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var newData = await _filesReader.GetData();
            _buffer.Add(newData); // will block until _buffer
                                  // has less than 10 items.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem happens before I actually add data to queue. First I need to parse the files to even get the data. My main issue is how to parse files partially (not everything at once)  and add data to queue iteratively.

Comment: @Loreno I addressed the point of your question for which you provided sample code. Having 1000 files is solved by setting the `boundedCapacity` of the `BlockingCollection`. For the other point, about how to parse the files in portions, I pointed out that it is impossible since you want to parse unbreakable formats like JSON.

Comment: Possibly you misunderstood the issue that I have. However, thanks for letting me know about JSON being "unbreakable". I did not really expect that. For now I'll go with a solution where I wil have FileHandlers. CsvFileHandler will work using streams, while JsonFileHandler will load all data into memory at once.

Comment: @Loreno I don't understand how streams are going to help you to balance your workload. Creating a stream is almost zero work. Passing streams to the parser means that you are delegating all the work, reading-and-parsing the file, to the parser. Also it is unclear to me what happens with the parsed data of the partial CSV input. If you store all parsed data of each file in memory then you have a similar problem of high memory consumption at the other end of the workflow, exaggerated from the fact that parsed data usually require more memory than raw data.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Using a stream to read a file aprtially VS reading the whole file at once - of course streams is a better solution. I'm not passing stream to a parser - FilesReader gets some part of file from stream, turns it into String and then passes that to parser. Parsed data is sent into queue, from which OutputHandler takes the data and writes it to some place. This is just a Producer/Consumer type of thing. So, concluding, if I parse just a part of file, I can already sent it into queue for further handling, while, at the same time, the rest of the file gets read.

Comment: It is easier to read partially a file using [`ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines), than handling the stream directly. Streams are always used under the hoods. The only option is between handling them directly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with some idea. My main goal is to have `FilesReader` that does not rely on any specific way of how data is transfered from it. All it should do is to read data, return it, and not care about any queues, or whatever else I could use. That's a job of `InputHandler` - it knows about the queue and it's using `FilesReader` to get some data to put in that queue.

I changed `FilesReader` interface a bit. Now it has a method like this:

```cs
Task ReadData(IFileInfo file, Action<IEnumerable<IDataPoint>> resultHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Now, `InputHandler` invokes the method like this:

```cs
await _filesReader.ReadData(file, data => _queue.Enqueue(data), cancellationToken);
```

I think it its a good solution in terms of separation of concerns.

`FilesReader` can read data in chunks and whenever a new chunk is parsed, it just invokes the delegate - and continues working on the rest of the file.

What do you think about such solution?